# SharedPreferences return same value even after editing

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I changed shared preferences value but it still returns old one. What am I missing?

This code executed when the user clicks on the item in RecyclerView. So on the first click, I get message `" this true"` as expected. But on second click I also get `" this true"`, but expect `"this false"`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean value = prefs.getBoolean(KEY_PREF, true);
    if (value) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "this true");
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "editing value..");
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        prefs.putBoolean(KEY_PREF, new_value);
        prefs.apply();
    } else {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "this false");
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `new_value` ? Maybe you should save `!value` instead. This will toggle the value.

Answer (score 3):

All you store is `true`, always, so there's no way to show `this false` as it never gonna happen. In fact, your code will not compile as `new_value` is never declared not assigned.

PS: there's no sense to call `getSharedPreferences()` second time. You got it already in `prefs` prior entering your `if()` block.

Comment: yeah, sorry. Actually i put newValue there

Comment: this is just piece of code. i've all declared and assigned

Answer (score 0):

The call `prefs.apply` is asynchronously. You may not see the immediate change. Instead you could use `prefs.commit` which is synchronously.